# Sending FormData with a binary data by using jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'd want to send a `FormData` by using jQuery AJAX, like:

```
var uploadFormData = new FormData();
uploadFormData.append("name","value");

$.ajax({
    url : "(URL_target)",
    type : "POST",
    data : uploadFormData,
    cache : false,
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
    success : function(r) {
        alert("Success!");
    }
});
```

But I also want to send a binary data by using jQuery AJAX, like:

```
var data = (...);

$.ajax({
    url: "(URL_target)",
    type: "POST",
    data : data,
    cache : false,
    contentType: "application/octet-stream",
    processData: false,
    success : function(r) {
        alert("Success!");
     }
});
```

How can I combine them into one data and send it out?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can append binary data to `FormData` object as a `Blob`, `File`, `ArrayBuffer` object, or `data URI`

```
var uploadFormData = new FormData();
var data = (...);
uploadFormData.append("name","value");
uploadFormData.append("data", new Blob([data], {type:"application/octet-stream"}));

$.ajax({
  url : "(URL_target)",
  type : "POST",
  data : uploadFormData,
  cache : false,
  contentType : false,
  processData : false,
  success : function(r) {
    alert("Success!");
  }
});
```