# Can't save uploaded video's blob URL at the backend server using AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl, html5-video, client-server

I have a web page where user uploads a video file using html's "input type = file" tag, I am catching that uploaded video file in JavaScript function variable where it is coming as blob URL. "blob:https://www.myownsite.com:8080/2e8cfd32-abf2-4db3-b396-91f76cc3b40c". I am not able to save this blob URL in my system.

HTML code:

```
<input type="file" name="video_file_name" accept="video/*">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Video" id="customVideoSubmit">
<button onClick="postVideo();" id="customVideoSubmit" aria- hidden="true">Upload Video</button>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function postVideo(){
 var blobURL = document.querySelector('video').src;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://myapplication.com',
        data: { videoData : blobURL , mediafilename : fileName},
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function() {
            console.log("Video saved successfully.");
        }
    });
}
```

variable blobURL contains following blob URL, which plays video properly if I put this on a separate tab of that browser.

```
blob:https://www.myownsite.com:8080/2e8cfd32-abf2-4db3-b396-91f76cc3b40c
```

How can I save this blob video file in my system. I have tried number of JavaScript methods and also back end methods in my Perl code like?

Nothing worked though. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to save a video or a video url?

Comment: What is the purpose of `POST`ing `Blob URL` to server?

Answer (score 1):

A `Blob URL`s lifetime is tied to the `document` where the `Blob URL` is created. If the `document` which created the `Blob URL` is closed the previously created `Blob URL` should be revoked, see [8.6. Lifetime of Blob URLs](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#lifeTime).

You can `POST` the `Blob` or  `File` object itself to server [Trying to Pass ToDataURL with over 524288 bytes Using Input Type Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37491759/trying-to-pass-todataurl-with-over-524288-bytes-using-input-type-text/); or a `FormData` object with `File` set as value [Sending FormData with a binary data by using jQuery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39218673/sending-formdata-with-a-binary-data-by-using-jquery-ajax/); or `data URI` representation of `File` object to server [Upload multiple image using AJAX, PHP and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856729/upload-multiple-image-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/).