# can anyone help to get fileinput object from image url

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone help me to get file-input object from image url

Sample image url :

https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/bright-spring-view-cameo-island-260nw-1048185397.jpg

Can anyone help me to get file object

By file object i mean the below format

[image]

Any fiddle will be highly thankful

Comment: Not possible, because the server doesn't send along that information, afaik. You can only get that for files the user selects in the context of a `<input type="file">`

Comment: @ChrisG i do have image url only handy and backend is expecting the file object . Am not uploading , already uploaded file with url only

Comment: or else is it possible to get fileinput object from base64 object . i can convert url to base64 , from there to file object . is there any way @ChrisG

Comment: I guess you're trying to upload the image to your own backend? You should be able to create a Blob from the image and insert that into a FormData object. Note that if this is what you're trying to do, your question is an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and you should edit it to tell us what your actual goal is.

Comment: @ChrisG - i have an image url handy , from that i need to convert the same to file input . no matter i i convert to base64 or blob , anyway if there any possibility to get fileobject from image url

Comment: You say the backend is expecting a File object. Can you confirm that this is about uploading via POST request?

Comment: yes  we are using POST request @ChrisG

Comment: 1. load the image 2. create a blob 3. append the blob to a FormData object 4. send the post request (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39218720/5734311)

Comment: @ChrisG i tried but am. getting CORS Issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62938489/when-tried-to-convert-to-base64-from-url-getting-cors-issue-in-js issue am facing :(

Comment: @ChrisG https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62938489/when-tried-to-convert-to-base64-from-url-getting-cors-issue-in-js am getting this when tried to do

Comment: You can circumvent the CORS issue if you use an `<img>` and set its `src`; loading the image using fetch will only work if shutterstock explicitly allows grabbing their images, not very likely.